Incorrect output of basic object oriented code
So i have a simple object oriented C# code which doesn't behave as expected.
Here is my object class :
internal class Fighter
{
    public int Id { get; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    int Health { get; set; } = 100;
    int Height { get; set; } = 180;
    int Weight { get; set; } = 78;
    static Weapon weapon { get; set; }
    int WeaponValue { get; } = (int)weapon;
    int DealedDamage { get; set; } = 0;
    bool IsMale { get; set; } = true;
    internal Random Random { get; private set; } = new Random();
    bool IsDead { get; set; } = false;

    public Fighter(int id, string name, Weapon weap) { this.Id = id; this.Name = name; weapon = weap;}

public void Description()
 {
     Console.WriteLine("Fighter ID : " + Id + ", Name : " + Name + ", Weapon : " + weapon + ", dealing " + WeaponValue + " pts of damage.");
 }
 }

My 'Weapon' enum :
internal enum Weapon { Couteau = 1, Machette = 3, Pistolet = 5, Grenade = 10, Mitraillette = 15, Fusil = 30 }

And finally my Program.cs class :
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, World!");
            Console.WriteLine("Bienvenue dans le programme de baston.");
            Fighter fighter1 = new Fighter(0, "Gaston", Weapon.Couteau);
            Fighter fighter2 = new Fighter(1, "Francis", Weapon.Grenade);
            fighter1.Description();
            fighter2.Description();
   
        }
    }

I get this output running my code in debug mode in Visual Studio 2022 :
Hello, World!
Bienvenue dans le programme de baston.
Fighter ID : 0, Name : Gaston, Weapon : Grenade, dealing 0 pts of damage.
Fighter ID : 1, Name : Francis, Weapon : Grenade, dealing 1 pts of damage.

Sortie de C:\Users\donna\Desktop\FightingTournament\bin\Debug\net6.0\FightingTournament.exe (processus 23112). Code : 0.
Pour fermer automatiquement la console quand le débogage s'arrête, activez Outils->Options->Débogage->Fermer automatiquement la console à l'arrêt du débogage.
Appuyez sur une touche pour fermer cette fenêtre. . .

It is not what I expected, I should have different weapons for the 2 objects I instantiated.
How is this possible ?
Thanks for reading
I tried placing the enum in its own namespace.
I tried changing visibility of the enum etc.
I also tried passing different values for Weapon variable.
Every time the output is incorrect.

Not only is the weapon incorrect but the weaponvalue too.

your Weapon-property is static, so all instances of your class share the exact same object. Reove the static-keyword from  the property.

Your weapon property is static, which means it's related to the type rather than any given instance of the type. It's not clear why you've done that, but it shouldn't be static if you want each Fighter to have a separate weapon.

Note that if you'd written this.weapon = weap;, consistently with the other assignments in the constructor, the compiler would have issued an error.

Next, you're assigning WeaponValue at the point of initialization - so even if weapon changes value, WeaponValue won't. (It's not clear why you've got that property at all to be honest.)

@JonSkeet I assume OP didn't use this.weapon exactly because of this error. However it's not clear why the property is static in the first place

@MakePeaceGreatAgain: Yes, I suspect you're right. The lesson to learn is "when the compiler issues an error, make sure you really understand it rather than just doing whatever it takes to stop the compiler reporting it."

Hello, I used static keyword in order to be able to cast the enum value into an int. Otherwise the ide wouldn't allow me (I would get CS0236 error).

Because I want to be able to fetch both the enum Value and its int equivalent at the same time : is this possible ?

Why can't you simply use Weapon Weapon { get; set; } int WeaponValue { get => (int)Weapon; }?

Yes : that is the syntax I was looking for actually @JonathanWillcock. Thank you

So all in all I must declare a second property to get the int value, there is no other option ?

Your Weapon-property is static, which means all your class'  instances share the exact same object. However in your case you want to reference the property within a properties initial-value, which isn't allowed.
However even if that was allowed, you could only change the default value for your WeaponValue-property. Whenever you'd change your Weapon-property to something else, your WeaponValue wouldn't change, because it is get-only and only has an initial value set. However what you probably want instead is to change that value whenever someone changes Weapon.
So after all do this:
internal class Fighter
{
    Weapon weapon { get; set; }
    int WeaponValue => (int)weapon;
}


It's because you have marked weapon as static. This means all fighter classes share one weapon so all fighters will have the last weapon assigned to any fighter.
Just declare weapon as public and it will work as expected:
public Weapon weapon { get; set; }

In order to get the weapon value from a non static property, you need a computed property:
int WeaponValue 
{ 
    get
    {
        return (int)weapon;
    }
}


Alright very clear thank you. I declared it static in order to get the weapon value out of the enum, as I explained it in the comments section above.

Updated my answer to show how to do that with a non static property.
